# Getting an error unresolved refrence in corda contract?

Tags: corda, smartcontracts

My use case is similar to that of IOU use case. While writing contract for that i am getting the following error.

```
> Task :contracts:compileKotlin FAILED
e: D:\Capstone_Tryout\contracts\src\main\kotlin\com\template\contracts\TradeContract.kt: (45, 34): Unresolved reference: signers
```

My code is are

```
package com.template.contracts

import com.template.states.TradeState
import net.corda.core.contracts.CommandData
import net.corda.core.contracts.Contract
import net.corda.core.contracts.requireSingleCommand
import net.corda.core.contracts.requireThat
import net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction

// ************
// * Contract *
// ************
class TradeContract :Contract {
    companion object {
        // Used to identify our contract when building a transaction.
        const val ID = "com.template.contracts.TradeContract"
    }

    // A transaction is valid if the verify() function of the contract of all the transaction's input and output states
    // does not throw an exception.

    override fun verify(tx: LedgerTransaction) {
        val command = tx.commands.requireSingleCommand<Commands>().value

        when(command) {
            is Commands.Issue -> requireThat {
                "There should be no input state" using (tx.inputs.isEmpty())
                "There should be one output state" using (tx.outputs.size == 1)

                "The output state should be of type TradeState" using (tx.outputs.get(0).data is TradeState)
                val outputState = tx.outputs.get(0).data as TradeState
                "TradeId should be 10 character long" using (outputState.TradeId.length == 10)

                val trade = tx.outputsOfType<TradeState>().single()
                "All of the participants must be signers." using (command.signers.toSet() == trade.participants.map { it.owningKey }.toSet())
                "A newly issued TradeState must have a positive amount." using (trade.Amount > 0)
                "The FromParty and ToParty cannot have the same identity." using (trade.FromParty != trade.ToParty)


            }
        }

        // Verification logic goes here.
    }

    // Used to indicate the transaction's intent.
    interface Commands : CommandData {
        class Issue : Commands
    }
}
```

While the similar code is working in corda example.

```
val iou = tx.outputsOfType<IOUState>().single()
"Both Parties together only may sign Trade issue transaction." using
                        (command.signers.toSet() == iou.participants.map { it.owningKey }.toSet())
```

I am not able to figure out why i am getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command wraps value and signers.

- Value is the type of the command
- Signers are the public keys of the required signers of the command.

The issue in the code above is :

```
val command = tx.commands.requireSingleCommand<Commands>().value
```

Replace the above with:

```
val command = tx.commands.requireSingleCommand<Commands>()
```

Answer (score 1):

Please confirm that you did the following:

1. Define the command inside your contract:

```java
public interface Commands extends CommandData {
    class Create implements Commands {}
}
```

2. Extract the command from the transaction inside your `verify()` method:

```java
final CommandWithParties<Commands.Create> command = 
                    requireSingleCommand(tx.getCommands(), Commands.Create.class);
```

Comment: yes, i have defined command inside contract. And about 2nd point, can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Can you update your question and share the entire code of `TradeContract.kt`?

Comment: Change `val command = tx.commands.requireSingleCommand<Commands>().value` to `val command = tx.commands.requireSingleCommand<Commands.Issue>()`